# How to update whatsapp with new apple ID

Tags: iphone, itunes-store, whatsapp.app

I need someone to help me 
I got this iphone5 a months ago from my cousin and I already have my own appleID and also my iCloud, and I could download the apps and everything but now when I got a notice to update whatsapp it requires the old password :/ is the only solution to delete whatsapp or is there anything else I could do?
P.S my cousin doesn't know the password 
Thank you

Comment: Hi  Christine, go to [Help Center > Contact](http://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) and select   "I need to merge user profile", please do not ask the same question twice

Answer (score 0):

When the iPhone wasn't ereased before you got it, the whatsapp app belongs to the apple id used by your cousin.

The only ways to update whatsapp are deleting it (by holding the app and pressing the "X"-symbol) and download it again with your own apple id, or use the password that belongs to the old apple id.